# why does this code throw undefined in "strict mode"

Tags: javascript

Why does this code throw `undefined`?

```
function Obj() {
   this.a = 12;
   this.b = "a";
   this.privilegedMethod = function () {
      this.a++;
      privateMethod();
   };

   function privateMethod() {
     this.b = "foo";
     console.log(this.b);
   }
}
```

Calling the function like below, throws... undefined in "Strict Mode".

```
var a = new Obj();
console.log(a.privilegedMethod());
```

Comment: What do you expect `this` to be in `privateMethod`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The value of `this` in JavaScript is set based on how a function is called.  It's the "context".

When you `a.privilegedMethod()`, you are calling `privilegedMethod()` in the "context" of `a`.  Inside, that method, `this` will be `a`.

When you call `privateMethod()`, there is no "context".  Outside of strict mode, `this` would be `window`, but in strict mode it's `undefined`.

Try this: `privateMethod.call(this);`.

Comment: I still get undefined when i try to call the privledge method from the context "a". http://jsfiddle.net/ywrosb8y/

Comment: Where do you get `undefined`?  ..OH!  That's because you are doing `console.log(a.privilegedMethod());`.  `privilegedMethod()` doesn't return anything?  What did you expect that to log?

Comment: P.S. The jsFiddle you posted in your comment doesn't do what you think it does.  That code is *not* running in strict mode.  When `privateMethod()` is called, it's setting `window.b`!  You *still* need to do `privateMethod.call(this);`.

Comment: Thanks Rocket, from where i need to call privateMethod.call(this), i am getting confused here? and also in latest browser it by default in strict mode right?

Comment: I'm not sure if browsers default to strict mode, I think you need to add the `'use strict';` command.  Also, just simply replace the line `privateMethod();` with `privateMethod.call(this);`.

Answer (score 1):

Because the privateMethod is not a method, it's just a function in the constructor scope, so `this.b = "foo";` is not pointing to your instance, so it's looking for `window.b`. In strict mode that flags undefined.