# Why does my function get undefined in strict mode (function form)?

Tags: javascript

Basically I have an image in my page that I can click to open it in a modal. I was previously using 'strict mode' (simple form) but since I try to be JSHint compliant, I changed it for the function form. Now I have my function openModal()
getting undefined.

```
<!-- Media part -->
    <ul class="netreviews_media_part">
        <!-- media 1 (picture) -->
        <li>
            <a data-type="image" data-src="https://www.expertisez.com/images/easyblog_images/511/Authentifier-un-sac-Chanel.jpg"
                       class="netreviews_image_thumb" href="javascript:" onclick="openModal(this);"
                       style="background-image:url('https://www.expertisez.com/images/easyblog_images/511/Authentifier-un-sac-Chanel.jpg');">&nbsp;</a>
        </li>
    <ul>
```

JS code (part of)

```
(function () {
    "use strict";
    function openModal(identifier) {
    // stuff here 
    }
}());
```

Fiddle here : https://jsfiddle.net/7zd6mc65/2/

I kinda seem to understand why it doesn't work, thanks to Rockets answer on this question ([why does this code throw undefined in "strict mode"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26811572/why-does-this-code-throw-undefined-in-strict-mode)) : apparently due to the 'lack of' context, my function context isn't getting defined anymore. 
Two things here though: 
1 - Why does the simple 'string' form ('strict mode' without the function form) doesn't make it a problem ? My openModal function isn't getting undefined using that.
2 - I tried to openModal.call(this) in the HTML but it didn't give me much more result (as seen in the answer but I guess Im mistaken)

What can I do to solve this? thanks

Comment: What are you trying to refer to with the `this`?

Comment: @TomNijs I try to refer to the object that has been clicked

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This has nothing to do with strict mode. Function declarations are scoped in the same way as `var` variables.

You have defined `openModal` inside an IIFE. The variable `openModal` is scoped to that IIFE. It is not a global.

---

If you want to make it a global, then you need to do so explicitly.

**Don't do this**. Globals risk namespace clashes.

```
window.openModal = openModal;
```

---

Since the late 90s, we've had `addEventListener`, so you don't need to express this as a global in order to use it as an event handler.

```
(function () {
    "use strict";
    addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function () {
        var thumbs = document.querySelectorAll(".netreviews_image_thumb");
        thumbs.forEach(function (element) {
            element.addEventListener("click", openModal);
        });
    });
    function openModal(event) {
        var identifier = this;
    }
}());
```

---

An aside:

> ```
> href="javascript:"
> ```

If you don't want to link anywhere, then don't use a link. Use `<button type="button">` instead. Better yet, link somewhere useful and have a server side fallback.

Comment: Oh ok, I understand that, but what can I do to make it global and still keeping strict mode IIFE? Or atleast make its scope available... sorry for the misuse of terms

Comment: Oh ok thanks, well actually I didnt write the HTML part, but yeah it seems logic. Though I can't edit that HTML or at least I would need to talk about that to my superior. What do you mean by having a server fallback in this case? its not clear to me...

Comment: Actually now my closeModal function also gets undefined... I guess I have to do the same for it ? Also, now I need to remove the onclick from every <a> tag ? Since its popping me an error still (just want to make sure here)

Comment: I feel like it is a lot of hassle, did I miss something here or will I always need to do things that way when using strict mode?

Comment: It is a lot of hassle, but that's one of the problems with using `onclick` *attributes* and why they fell out of fashion twenty years ago.

Comment: Tell that to my company :p
So ideally I would need to get rid of these onclick things right? And add another event listener for the closeModal function? I will see what I can/am allowed to do (but please confirm that first :) )